# Enable Maven support IntelliJ IDEA 2022

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I just updated IntelliJ IDEA from 2021.3 to 2022.1, and it appears I lost maven support.

I have a scala plugin, which was automatically installed, but I've never had to do anything to have the option to build a project as a maven project, but now that option is gone. The new menu format offers me native IntelliJ, or Gradle.

If I look for plugins, there are a ton of them, but they all appear to be "extra features", and none of them (that I can see, it's hard to be sure with so many) are actually core JetBrains tools (which I would expect this to be).

Here is the new project window, offering IntelliJ and Gradle build systems, but not maven. The IntelliJ page shows a screenshot of this page that *includes* maven.

[image]

Since I suspect this will be the next question from kind folks trying to help, here's the window I get if I try to "add framework support" to the project:

[image]

Again, Maven's not on the list.

Also, FWIW, this is my command line:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /home/simon/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 17.0.1, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /usr/local/jdk-17.0.1+12
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-117-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

What can I try next?

Comment: `the option to build a project as a maven project, but now that option is gone` where exactly are you expecting this option? A screenshot would help.

Comment: Also, make sure the **Maven** plugin is enabled in IDE **Plugins** settings

Comment: There is no obvious "maven" plugin. A bunch of third party "maven-xxx" plugins, but none that look like "the one", and none that I can see from JetBrains. I'll show the screenshot for the options that don't include maven above.

Comment: There is **Maven** already bundled plugin. It must be enabled.

Comment: Indeed, there is @Andrey. However, the problem was a bug in the upgrade process from 2021 to 2022, which disabled it for no obvious reason. So, the "answer" was to remove the entry from (or the file) disabled_plugins.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can add Maven framework to your module by right clicking the module -> Add Framework Support and selecting Maven.

Comment: So... You're saying I have to make the project first, *then* add maven to it?

Comment: Actually, when I do this, Maven is not on the list. I see Groovy, Kotlin/JVM, and Scala. But that's all. It's like IntelliJ itself doesn't have the support.

Comment: Does you installed plugins include bundled Maven plugins?

Comment: There are about 20 "maven-xxx" plugins, and they're all third party. I don't even see a simple maven plugin (and I never needed one before). So, I'm not sure how to move forward. Further, there is no option for maven in "framework support".

Comment: I also don't see Maven as an option.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, to move it to the correct place)*.

The solution, courtesy of the IntelliJ forum, is that for reasons I didn't ask about, the installation had a file "disabled_plugins.txt" which explicitly named Maven. This file was in the config directory, and for me, on Linux, was: `~/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/disabled_plugins.txt`.

Deleting that file and restarting allows everything to work as expected.